# Exponentiation of Gell-Mann Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

The exponentiation of Pauli vector $\vec \sigma=(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$ is trivial as we have the identity:$$e^{ia(\vec n\cdot \vec \sigma)}=I cos(a)+i(\vec n \cdot \vec \sigma)sin(a)$$

I have been studying the properties of Gell-Mann matrices and was wondering whether a similar exponentiation  is possible or not. I used Mathematica to explicitly compute the exponentials of individual Gell-Mann matrices and I am getting exact solutions.

Though, the exponentials of Gell-Mann matrices can be obtained explicitely I was trying to obtain an identity similar to the above one for Pauli matrices. The major property of Pauli matrices which enable the derivation of the above identity is that $\sigma_i^2=I$. But, the Gell-Mann matrices in general does not have this property.

Is it possible to derive a similar identity? If yes, I would like to receive some hints on how to achieve the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here; the Gell-Mann matrices form a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, and the usual matrix exponential gives a map $\mathfrak{su}(3) \to SU(3)$. The main difference is that the Gell-Mann matrices don't square to $1$, so the sum doesn't readily collapse into a nice form.

Comment: But, in the case of Pauli matrices which forms the basis of SU(2) we have an identity as given above involving cosine and sine functions. My question is whether a similar identity can be derived for the exponential of a Gell-Mann matrix or not.

Comment: I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#n_.3D_3) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered affirmatively and in detail in the following paper:

Thomas L. Curtright and Cosmas K. Zachos, *Elementary results for the fundamental representation of SU(3)*, Rept. Math. Phys. **76** (2015), 401-404.
e-Print: [arXiv:1508.00868v2 [math.RT]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00868v2)